# JavaFx Rotate Images

Tags: java, image, javafx

I made a player class. In this Class i made a draw Method. 
This method returns a Image. In the main class i draw this Image with graphicContext.
I want to rotate the Image, but i dont Know how.

Please help me solve this Problem

```
 public Image draw(){

    return playerNormalImg;
}
```

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `Canvas` to rotate your `Image`, as you are programming a chess board, i guess you want to rotate `180 degrees`

```
Canvas canvas = ...
Image image = ...
GraphicsContext graph = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

graph.save(); 
graph.rotate(180);
graph.drawImage(image);
graph.save();
```